# Hive Select Count(*) filenotfound exception for job.splitmetainfo

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a hiveserver2 running and wrote a java program to query from hive.

I tried this query

```
SELECT * FROM table1
```

where, 'table1' is the table name in hive, and its works fine and gave me the results.

But when i tried to run

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1
```

it threw an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
```

I check the logs and this was recorded

```
Job init failed : org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://vseccoetv04:9000/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/anonymous/.staging/job_1453359797695_0017/job.splitmetainfo
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl$InitTransition.createSplits(JobImpl.java:1568)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl$InitTransition.transition(JobImpl.java:1432)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl$InitTransition.transition(JobImpl.java:1390)
....
```

I checked in a number of places, and other people too got 'FileNotFoundException' but not dude to this reason.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,

I figured out the problem myself :)

I had added some properties in the hive-site.xml file earlier to check support for transactions. I think i might have added some wrong values there. Now, I have removed the properties which i added, and have restarted hive service. Everything works fine :D